# How to deploy react native for web app to azure environment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I try to deploy a Azure react native for web app to the Azure environment.

So I created a web app in azure. And I am using a ftp program for uploading the files.

The address of the remote server is:

```
ftps://waws-prod-am2-781.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot
```

But now comes the strange thing. I deleted in the www root folder of the remote site the standard html file(hostingstart.html). And I uploaded the files from the created web-build react folder on my local host to the remote host to the wwwroot folder.

But if I go the the URL of the remote server:
```https://dierenwelzijnapp.azurewebsites.net````

I still see the text:

```
Hey, Python developers!
Your app service is up and running.
Time to take the next step and deploy your code.
Have your code ready?
Use deployment center to get code published from your client or setup continuous deployment.
```

How is this even possible? Because I deleted the file hostingstart.html.

And even when I go to

```
https://dierenwelzijnapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/fileManager#
```

I see filemanager --> site --> wwwroot with all the files and folders.

Question: In which directory from the remote site I have to upload the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated with react native:-***

I created one **`expo react-native app`** and then built it with **`expo build:web`** command and deployed web-build folder in my **Azure Web App Windows OS** based app. As React-native requires different folder structure in Linux based OS. It is recommended to use Windows OS:-

**My Azure Web App:-**

[image]

***Transferred the contents of web-build folder and not the entire web-build folder via FTP like below:-***

[image]

[image]

**The Web app runs successfully:-**

[image]

**With React App:-**

Make sure you are Deploying build folder in your Azure Web app like below:-

After I created one sample react App locally, I created a build folder that is a deployable Folder for my Azure Web app and uploaded the build folder content to my Azure Web App.

**Command:-**

```js
npm run build
```

After running npm build, build folder is created:-

[image]

In your Azure Web App Deployment Center > Visit FTP Credentials and connect to your Azure Web App remote server via Filezilla or WinScp FTP tool :-

[image]

Make sure Basic Auth is set to On and FTP only setting is enabled:-

[image]

My Web app is created on ***Runtime - Node 18*** as React works better with Node rather than Python and I am using ***Windows OS:***-

[image]

***My Filezilla setting:-***

[image]

My ***React App got loaded successfully after copying the contents***:-

[image]

**My Web App > Kudu>**

[image]

Comment: @siddheshdesai.Thank you. But Iti is a react native web app. So I have web-build folder. But are you online?

Comment: Yes, In react native, Deploy your web-build folder

Comment: But I have done all this steps.

Comment: Okay, Allow me some time to replicate with react native

Comment: @siddheshdesai.oke. But it is a react native for web. And you have to create the web-build folder with the command  expo build:web

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Sure..

Comment: @siddheshdesai.And did it work by you?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton It worked for me, check my Updated answer. I have used Azure Web app with Windows OS. And Node as runtime.

Comment: @siddheshdesaiHi. can we chat?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Yes, Sure